# What does SQL "SET a=1 AND b=2" means

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to create a query to update multiple records and by mistake I wrote the wrong version but it ran without any error.

Wrong version: `update table SET c1=1 AND c2=2`.

Can anyone explain what does it do and why don't it fails.

Comment: did it update your records

Comment: @Coding yes, all of them.

Comment: @Coding If I remember correctly, only c1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess:

```
update table SET c1=1 AND c2=2
```

is translated to:

```
update table 
SET c1 = (1 AND c2=2)
```

Then expression `(1 AND c2=2)` is evaluated and implicitly converted in order to update field `c1`.

So, if, for example, your table looks like this:

```
create table mytable (c1 int, c2 int);

insert into mytable values
(1, 3),
(2, 1),
(3, 2);
```

query:

```
SELECT c1, c2, 1 AND c2=2 AS expr
FROM mytable
```

returns:

```
c1, c2, expr
------------
1,  3,  0
2,  1,  0
3,  2,  1
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/GOAQAR80511)

Comment: Syntactically correct, but should still raise an error since 1 is an invalid boolean value.